# Connection from sails in ec2 to MySQL in rds giving handshake inactivity timeout error

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sails.js

I deployed my sails app in ec2 and I have mysql database in rds.

when I use mysql in rds from my local, it worked absolutely fine. But when I connect myswl in rds from the ec2 it is giving me this error:

```
error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load!
error: Error (E_UNKNOWN) :: Encountered an unexpected error
: Could not connect to MySQL:
Error: Handshake inactivity timeout
```

Please help me solve this issue. Should I configure my ec2 instance to connect to rds?

Answer (score 1):

When adding inbound connection in the security options, don't use anywhere. As you can imagine, this is not secure at all. Instead use the security group associated with your instance. Of course, if you want to connect to your database remotely, add only your external IP address to the rules. "Anywhere" is like an invitation to the whole world saying: "Try to hack me!"

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Added a inbound connection in security options with anywhere option.